# Yii2 checkboxlist validation without model

Tags: validation, yii2, checkboxlist

I have a list of checkboxes, which aren't associated with the model itself like the rest of the form:

```php
echo Html::checkboxList('options', $selected_options, $options, ['class' => 'checkbox']);
```

In the model I have a following rules:

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        ....*/
        [['options'], 'integer'],
        ['options', 'optValidation', 'on' => 'update'],
    ];
}
```

And the following validator:

```php
public function optValidation($attribute, $params) {
    foreach ($attribute as $attr){
        if ($attr == 1) {
            $return = true;
        }
        else {
            $return = false;
        }
    }
    if (!$return) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'At least one checkbox has to be selected!');   
    }
}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens when submitting the form as if there are no rules for validation of the field 'options'. Where's the catch?

Comment: you can declare `option` as `public` in model then validate using model.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `break` statement in your loop?

Comment: `Option` is already declared as `public` in the model, @InsaneSkulll. Also tried having `Option` as `Option[]` as it is array, but no luck. @robsch, I was wondering about it, but even having just `$this->addError()` in the method there's no change.

Comment: if you declared `public $option` the why not using it with model in form? If you will not add `model` in `checkbox`, it simply skips your validation rules because it doesn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `options` as a public attribute inside your model class. Then you need to set it as safe inside your rules:

```
public function rules() {
    ...
    [['options'], 'integer'],
    [['options'], 'optValidation', 'on' => 'update'],
    [['options'], 'safe'],
    ...
```

Finally, you will have to generate the input just like other inputs related to your model, even if it doesn't exist in your DB table, you need it inside your model:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'options')->checkboxList('options', $selected_options, $options, ['class' => 'checkbox']); ?>
```